# How can I make firebase realtime dtabase to act as a webhook endpoint

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback, callbackurl

I am trying to use firebase realtime database, to convert it to a webhook endpoint. Can I use the database url, or is there any other way?

I tried changing the extension of the database url to include a .json extension, but whenever I send a requent I don't see anything change in the database

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database has a well documented [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) that may be usable as a web hook. Check the documentation of your sending platform to see if its data format it compatible with the format Firebase requires.

If the data formats aren't compatible, you can consider using something like [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#integrate_with_third-party_services_and_apis) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/webhooks) to serve as the web hook, which then in turn writes to the database. This will give you more control over the operation, as the code you run can then handle any incoming data format and convert it to what the database expects.